# IQueryable Confusion

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about IQueriable. Maybe my understanding is wrong but I thought calling ToList() would force the query to execute. I have a PaginatedList class that I want to populate using an IQuerriable, but when I do it I get a series of null objects. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>  
{  
    public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)  
    {  
        PageIndex = pageIndex;  
        PageSize = pageSize;  
        TotalCount = source.Count();  
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);  
        List<T> temp = source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();  
        this.AddRange(temp);  
    }    
}
```

My temp List is being filled with default values. I don't understand. ANy help would be appreciated.

The list is populated as follows:

```
 public IQueryable<Transaction> GetTransactions()  
    {  
        return from trx in pingDataContext.Table0
        join pdo in pingDataContext.Table1
        on trx.AssociatedID equals pdo.ID  
        where trx.Type == 1 &&  
        pdo.PortalID == 330  
        select new Transaction(trx.ID, pdo.CreateDate, pdo.Msisdn, pdo.Remarks, 0.1, 
                               (double)pdo.Price, pdo.DnldLink, pdo.UserIP);  
    }
```

I am creating my paginated list here:

```
var transactions = transactionRepository.GetTransactions();  
var paginatedTransactions = new PaginatedList<Transaction>(transactions,
                                                           (int)page,
                                                           pageSize);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use IQueryable<T> as the parameter. It would work just fine with IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: I want the query to only be formed at this stage, to take load of the db.

Comment: Further you are enumerating the list three times. one for .CounT(), one for ToList() and one for AddRange. Since you're not using TotaqlPages (at least not in the code above) you can get rid of two of them (Count and to list)

Comment: but that has nothing to do with you input parameter. That won't gauranteed anything about what has already been done. IQueryable<T> is also IEnumerbale<T> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) so anything you pass for source will be passble

Comment: Passing it as IEnumerable will cause the paging to occur on the client side rather than the server side. It should be passed in as IQueryable to retain and modify the expression tree adding the Skip/Take portions.

Answer (score 1):

You say your list is filled with default values. If you mean `default(T)`, than this is the problem:
`default(T)` returns `null` it `T` is a reference type.
Your usage of `ToList()` has nothing to do with this. It isn't even necessary in your code. The following would be equivalent:

```
var temp = source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
this.AddRange(temp);
```

The reason is that `AddRange` will enumerate the passed enumerable anyway.

Comment: Hi Daniel, so does this mean I can only have this kind of list for primitive types? Or how can I solve this?

Comment: @Steve: No, this conclusion is not correct. You should simply fill your list with real objects instead of `null`. Please update your question with the code that creates the list. Then, I might be able to help more.

Comment: Now I don't really understand your problem anymore. Is the problem that `temp` contains 0 items or that it contains multiple items but all are `null`?

Comment: Every item in the Paginated list seems to be default. For the Object in question, a Transaction, every string is null, every int is 1, and the DateTime is 0001/01/01 00:00:00. Nonetheless, I get a full list of objects. I am really lost myself here :-P

Comment: In fact, even the value I am hardcoding at 0.1, a double, somehow becomes 0. It's a paginated list of identical default objects. I'm baffled.. Thanks for your help anyways.